# Can I commit/push a file omitting certain comments in git?

Tags: git, github

Suppose that a friend and I are working on a file `work.txt`, which is located at a **github** repository. I want to make some comments on this file that are present on my local copy but don't get pushed when I update. Is this possible to do with **git**?

Imagine for example that this file is some code and I want to add as a comment some information about a function so that I remember that myself, but as my friend remembers what the function does very clearly he doesn't need the comment there. I would like this comment to appear in my local file but not in the repository. Moreover, I would like that when the file gets updated, the comment remains in the updated version in my local machine (otherwise I could simply keep a local copy and overwrite comments upon updates).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I suppose it's admirable that people are trying to provide solutions rather than just say "no it's not possible", the solutions offered mostly will do more harm than good.  They typically involve perpetually keeping uncommitted/unstaged changes in your work tree, which is unstable at best.

The closest to a workable solution is Gonzalo Matheu's suggestion to use clean/smudge filters.  Even that is far from a slam dunk.  (It's easy enough for a clean filter to be written that can recognize and remove certain comments, but getting the smudge filter to work reliably... that's harder.)

The short answer is, this is not functionality provided by git.

That doesn't mean you couldn't create tooling to assist with it, if for some reason it's worth it.  (And if it sounds like I'm implying it's not worth it... well, it does rather seem like you're trying to find a technical solution for a social problem - being that you and your friend can't agree on what lever of code comment is appropriate.)

You could certainly come up with some sort of documentation file for your own use, to be either stored outside the work tree or given filenames that can be matched by an ignore pattern (`*.mydoc` or something).  These files would contain enough information to determine where each comment is to be inserted, and then you could write a script to combine them into your work files.  Provided they did this in a conspicuous way such that the comments can be removed using a simple clean filter, then you could use the "combiner" script as your smudge filter, as one way to complete Mr. Matheu's suggested approach.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer, it's good to put the other answer in perspective. Your comments on the other questions also help a lot, without disregarding these answers of course. Maybe you could refer to this situation as a 'social problem', but it's actually just a matter of making a difference between personal documentation vs 'public' documentation, I think it's reasonable to categorize some comments as private and some others as public, and to keep two updated versions seems like a reasonable functionality.

Comment: In any case, as Gonzalo and you point out this is most likely an overkill and probably I will end up just scripting it. I want to give it a try to the other solutions though, just for fun :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Git smudge and clean filters](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#filters_a) which allows you to do substitutions in files on commit/checkout using custom scripts. Where **smudge** means *execute this code whenever you check anything out* and 
**clean** means *Run this code whenever you check anything in*.

The **clean** filter script will have to remove all your comments, you might have to prefix it with a special pattern. And also save those comments into an auxiliar diff file.

The **smudge** filter will have to apply the auxiliar diff file to the original file in order to restore your comments.

Using this you will not need to do anything special before committing. I.e: just commit, and the clean filter will handle your working copy comments.

There are a few repos with examples:

- https://github.com/CodeRevver/smudge-clean
- https://github.com/gilesbowkett/git-smudge-and-clean

**Anyway, it feels like an overkill**, additional comments will not hurt in the repository and will work as documentation if they are written properly.

Comment: I understand how the clean filter would work; how do you expect the smudge filter to work?

Comment: For the *smudge*, it might need an auxiliar file (probably a diff) and apply it to the original file. This auxiliar file will be generated during *clean* .

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this with git, though you will have to specify which parts of the file you want to commit every time you update the file. To do this, add the file in 'hunks' with the -p (patch) flag to `git add`, rather than in its entirety:

`git add work.txt -p`

You will be taken to an interactive prompt asking you if you would like to stage a particular part of the file.  Respond with `y` or `n`, or one of the commands [other possible options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#_interactive_mode) -- choose `n` for the commented parts you don't want to commit.

Finally, what you are trying to do is an unusual thing to do with git, this solution is essentially shoehorning git to work in a case it wasn't really designed for. In a production codebase, comments would be committed but might be removed before deployment by a build tool.

Comment: This is not a reasonable solution to the problem, because it means you are forever keeping certain changes "unstaged".  First of all, you **will** stage them accidentally at some point (i.e. by saying `git add .`).  Secondly, because you have local changes to the file, you'll have problems pulling, merging, or changing branches.  In short, you **cannot** preserve "local" changes in this way.